# How to book a multi-part flight with Turkish airlines?

Tags: online-resources, airlines, bookings

I've found some interesting flights using [Matrix Airfare Search](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) that involve [Turkish Airlines](http://www.turkishairlines.com). The problem is that these flights are like this:

*Go: MAD - DEL*

*Return: BOM - MAD*

Matrix Airfare Search cannot book flights and send me to the Turkish website, but I cannot find any way to book return tickets that have a different return city (and if I book two only one way flights the sum of prices do not match the Matrix result). How can I book this?

**EDIT**: Using the multi-leg searcher, the prices don't match the prices offered by Matrix. It matches the sum of prices of the individual legs.

Comment: Have you tried asking a Travel Agent? They're normally much better than a website for complicated requests!

Comment: I'm not sure if things have changed since Google purchased ITA, but the Matrix was not always reliable for checking availability. That is, it could find you a legal routing and fare, but was not especially accurate as to whether it was possible to purchase it; the fare could be sold out, or the airline could have zeroed its inventory. You can try booking on another site (e.g. Orbitz, CheapTickets) or a travel agent. In the past, I've simply called airlines directly and asked for a particular routing and fare, though they have not always been able to get them for me.

Comment: Mmhhh.. so ITA is not always reliable. Perhaps that's the point.. I don't know :(

Comment: I've found ITA extremely reliable for constructing fares, it's just that its view of availability is not always the same as what the travel agent sees.  And yes, airlines' own multi-leg searches are usually worthless, they just add up full-price one-ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth nothing that return flights are always from A-B-A.  You're asking for an open-jawed (sort-of) flight - and that's almost always two one-way tickets.  Sometimes on kayak.com they have variants that'll show up if you select multiple airports in your "return flight" - you could try that (in the "from" box, you can put MAD, and in the "to" box, put "DEL,BOM.  However it may just find the cheapest return flight to DEL then.  But it could be worth a try.

I'd suggest [Flightfox](http://flightfox.com/) as another possible option.  It's like an online travel agent - you pay a small fee, and their experts find the cheapest flight they can for you.

What you could do is create a contest on there, and indicate what you've found, but that you'd like a way to book it for the price you've found, or for less if they can ;)

(disclaimer, I occasionally compete on there as an expert - there's a discount link in my profile)

Comment: The OP's fare sounds like a perfectly normal open-jaw to me, and they're often way cheaper than two one-ways.  Booking these online will be difficult, but if he can print out the fare construction from Matrix, any halfway competent travel agent should be able to book it.

Comment: Indeed, but given he's on here and using itasoftware, I assumed he wasn't up for using a travel agent. And indeed they may not match the price indicated in itasoftware, but you're right - they should be able to book it.

Comment: @MarkMayo I don't understad Flightfox. I have to pay $29 and if the experts couldn't find a price better than mine I lose the money? And another question, they will book my flight or Flightfox only gives me the information to book myself the flight?

Comment: @Ivan last I checked, if they can't beat your genuine price, you get a refund (I did last year when I'd found a good YVR->SFO price).  However, they were amazing for saving me money other times.  They give you the information on how to book it. Currently you then book it yourself, but they're looking at adding that functionality to the site in the future so that it can be done by them for you.